# Why do I get invalid pom due to missing dependency.version although the version is managed?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have case that looks like this:

**super**

- dependency manangement of thrid-party

**parent-pom**

- child of super

**projectA**

- child of parent-pom
- dependency to third-party

**projectB**

- child of parent-pom
- dependency to projectA

projectA builds just fine, but when I try to compile projectB I get:

[WARNING] The POM for [projectA] is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problems were encountered while building the effective model for [projectA]

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for thrid-party.jar is missing. @

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you indicate the thrid-party.jar version in the POM?

Comment: In dependency management yes, in projectA no.

Comment: So, do it and let's see.

Comment: No, I want the version of third-party to be managed

Comment: Please, show us the Super and projectA POM files.

Comment: You will have to post your pom files here so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, will add pom's in a couple of minutes. I though it might be some conceptual mistake in the inheritance model or something like that.

Comment: These couple of minutes are getting really long ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install super to you local repo, just having relativePath set is not enough for this case.

Comment: A relative path should usually not been set if using a parent pom.

Comment: I can't find any information that supports this statement. From what I can find relativePath is just fine if you want a flat directory structure.

Comment: I have however seen that some plugins don't support flat directory structure. But that's not the issue here.